# Issue re-hiding div class on reselect of original option jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Can't seem to figure this out.  Value does change as it is supposed to, but "#donateForm" doesn't hide upon selection of original option.

```
<select id="donateSelect">
                        <option value="0">Select</option>
                        <option value="General Fund">General Fund</option>
                        <?php
                        // display all project names as options
                        $prj_sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `tbl_projects`";
                        $prj_result = mysqli_query($database_link, $prj_sql);
                        while ($prj = mysqli_fetch_array($prj_result)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$prj['name'].' Project Fund">'.$prj['name'].' Project Fund</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<div id="donateForm">
......
</div>

<script>
$('#donateForm').hide();
$('#donateSelect').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#donateSelect').val() == "0") {
        $('#donateForm').hide();
    } else {
        var donateValue = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
        $('#donateForm').show();
        $('#item_name').val(donateValue);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your #item_name input field?

Comment: I tried your code here, and the div is going to be hidden if i select the default value https://jsfiddle.net/o6efuoz6/